# Asp.net c#, Rollback or Commit after multiple process

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, advantage-database-server

I want to use Rollback() or commit() functions after multiple process.

There is no error, but it does not commit() to update DB.

Here is my example code,

```
public void startTransaction(){
    using(Ads_A_Connection = new AdsConnection(Ads_A_connection_string))
    using(Ads_B_Connection = new AdsConnection(Ads_B_connection_string))
    {
        Ads_A_Connection.Open();
        Ads_B_Connection.Open();

        AdsTransaction aTxn = Ads_A_Connection.BeginTransaction();
        AdsTransaction bTxn = Ads_B_Connection.BeginTransaction();

        try{
            string aResult = this.process1(Ads_A_Connection);       
            this.process2(Ads_B_Connection, aResult);       
            this.process3(Ads_A_Connection. Ads_B_Connection);

            aTxn.Commit();
            bTxn.Commit();
            // there is no error, but it couldn't commit.
        }catch(Exception e){
            aTxn.Rollback();
            bTxn.Rollback();
        }
    }
}

public string process1(conn){
    // Insert data
    return result;
}

public void process2(conn. aResult){
    // update
}

public void process3(aConn, bConn){
    // delete
    // update
}
```

I guess, its because out of using scope. because I tried to put all the code into
startTransaction() method, then it works. but it look too dirty.

How can I use rollback() or commit() after multiple (METHOD) process?

anybody know, please advice me.

Thanks!

[EDIT]

I just add TransactionScope before connection,

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
   using(Ads_A_Connection = new AdsConnection(Ads_A_connection_string))
   using(Ads_B_Connection = new AdsConnection(Ads_B_connection_string))
   {
     .
     .
```

but it makes an error, it say "**Error 5047: The transaction command was not in valid sequence.**"

I need a little more hint please :)

Comment: first commit inner/nested transaction then outer transaction

Comment: Re : 5047 - have you removed the manual BeginTransaction(), Commit() and Rollback()s on your connection? This is now managed by TransactionScope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend what Etch mentioned, their are several issues with manually managing transactions on your connections:

- You need to pass the SQL connection around your methods
- Need to manually remember to commit or rollback when you are finished
- If you have more than one connection to manage under a transaction, you should really use DTC or XA to enroll the transactions into a Distributed / 2 phase transaction.

TransactionScopes [are supported](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/advantage8.1/mergedProjects/ads-dotnet/base_ado_net_doc/transaction_support_in_the_advantage_net_data_provider.htm) with the Advantage Database Server, although you will need to enable the [MSDTC service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and possibly also enable XA compliance.

Note that I'm assuming that the advantage .NET client has some sort of connection pooling mechanism - this makes the cost of obtaining connections very lightweight.

Ultimately, this means that your code can be refactored to something like the following, which is easier to maintain:

```
private void Method1()
{
    using(Ads_A_Connection = new AdsConnection(Ads_A_connection_string))
    {
        Ads_A_Connection.Open();
        string aResult = this.process1(Ads_A_Connection);       
    } // Can logically 'close' the connection here, although it is actually now held by the transaction manager
}

private void Method2()
{
    using(Ads_B_Connection = new AdsConnection(Ads_B_connection_string))
    {
        Ads_B_Connection.Open();
        this.process2(Ads_B_Connection, aResult);       
    } // Can logically 'close' the connection here, although it is actually now held by the transaction manager
}


public void MyServiceWhichNeedToBeTransactional(){
    using(TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()) { // NB : Watch isolation here. Recommend change to READ_COMMITTED
        try{
           Method1();
           Method2();
           ts.Complete();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
          // Do Logging etc. No need to rollback, as this is done by default if Complete() not called
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using System.Transactions; (C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Transactions.dll)

Answer (score 0):

TransactionScope is your friend!

[TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)